# intents for chatBot using rasa_nlu

Tags: chatbot, rasa-nlu

I am trying to make a chatbot for the faqs of our website with rasa_nlu. There are about 200 frequently asked questions divided in some categories. Is it correct way to make intent for every question or should I follow some other approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please show us what you have done so far, add some code and the results. Make sure to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Before you start adding the Intents, there are few suggestions I have:

- Firstly try to categorize the questions that you, this will help you to identify if there is a unique purpose to be accomplished; which will be an Intent by itself.
- Order each questions and see if it serves to complete a single meaningful conversation serving a particular purpose, this will help you think about the Context functionality.
- At the end of the above exercise you should a mind-map that will show you the unique intents and the related questions to each of them.

The **goal will be to have a good user experience when someone is interacting with your chatbot and should complete the conversation in a natural flow** with a meaningful start and end.

Comment: will you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

There is a new FAQ component, see [this PR](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/pull/379)

This will go into the v0.9 release in the next couple of weeks, but you can already try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it easily with Rasa-core. You can use a distinctive intent for same questions. In domain.yml, you create an action for each intent, where action corresponds to the answer. Stores is just the (intent action) pair.

By default, memorization policy is used. As long as correct intent is detected by rasa-nlu, the correct answer will be given. I tried with mine, it works.